# how to check for invalid guid parameter passed in

Tags: c#, guid

I am trying to create some test data and i want to return and error message to the user that the passed in guid is not in valid format - an example of how this could be applied will be great

proper guid format that i am using:

```
Guid user = new Guid("FF2214F8-5393-4B5A-B1CA-3620F85D9131");
```

invalid guid that i pass in to test and would like to return a message to the user to notify rather than breaking:

```
Guid user2 = new Guid("UserName");
```

method i use to pass in:

```
public void UserName(user2)
{
....  
}
```

Comment: What is your current problem?

Comment: when i test what i have it breaks and gives the error message: `system.formatexception: guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes` i want to catch this before it breaks and report to user.\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly `user2` is the Guid you want to test, if so try [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx):

```
   Guid result;
    if(Guid.TryParse(user2, out result))
    {
    //success (result variable has been assigned the Guid value)
    }
    else
    {
    //error
    }
```

**Edit:** According to your comments, I understand that the problem is that you are passing that method an invalid Guid, so the exception happens when you create the variable that you are going to pass to the method as parameter. Does this helps?

```
Guid user2; 
if(Guid.TryParse("UserName", out user2))
{
 UserName(user2)
}
else
{
//do whatever you need to report the error
}
```

I'm not sure where do you get "UserName" but the point here is that wherever you are trying to create a `Guid` from a string and you're not sure if the string is valid you need to use `Guid.TryParse` method

Comment: when i compiled i got this error message: `Argument 1: cannot convert from system.guid to string` even though both usr and result are guids

Comment: it is a guid but i passed in a string instead of the 32 alpha numeric combo to test - is that what's causing it?

Comment: I thought `user2` was a string.. you will need to receive a string if you want to make this check in your method, otherwise this check should be done in the caller's code

Comment: can you change the parameter's type to string? that's the easiest solution

Comment: how about i do a try catch and then i could catch the `FormatException` and inform user that way through the `Console.writeline`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) method

```
Guid userGuid;
if (Guid.TryParse(user2, out userGuid))
{
   // Do something with the guid
}
else
{
   //throw exception...
}
```